# Using Codedom to write VB.Net Properties

Tags: .net, vb.net, codedom

Looking at the example code on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codepropertysetvaluereferenceexpression(loband).aspx):

This

```
    ' Declares a type.
    Dim type1 As New CodeTypeDeclaration("Type1")

    ' Declares a constructor.
    Dim constructor1 As New CodeConstructor
    constructor1.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public
    type1.Members.Add(constructor1)

    ' Declares an integer field.
    Dim field1 As New CodeMemberField("System.Int32", "integerField")
    type1.Members.Add(field1)

    ' Declares a property.
    Dim property1 As New CodeMemberProperty
    property1.Name = "integerProperty"
    property1.Type = New CodeTypeReference(GetType(Integer))
    ' Declares a property get statement to return the value of the integer field.
    property1.GetStatements.Add(New CodeMethodReturnStatement(New CodeFieldReferenceExpression(New CodeThisReferenceExpression, "integerField")))
    ' Declares a property set statement to set the value to the integer field.
    ' The CodePropertySetValueReferenceExpression represents the value argument passed to the property set statement.
    property1.SetStatements.Add(New CodeAssignStatement(New CodeFieldReferenceExpression(New CodeThisReferenceExpression, "integerField"), New CodePropertySetValueReferenceExpression))
    type1.Members.Add(property1)

    Dim dump As New VBCodeProvider
    Dim gen As Compiler.ICodeGenerator = dump.CreateGenerator
    Dim opt As New Compiler.CodeGeneratorOptions

    gen.GenerateCodeFromType(type1, Console.Out, opt)
```

should generate

```
Public Class Type1

   Private integerField As Integer

   Public Sub New()
       MyBase.New()
   End Sub

   Private Property integerProperty() As Integer
       Get
           Return Me.integerField
       End Get
       Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
           Me.integerField = value
       End Set
   End Property
End Class
```

But I'm not seeing it generate the parameter to the Set method, I.e. I get:

```
       Set
           Me.integerField = value
       End Set
```

Given that I already had to add in bits to the example code to actually name the property to match their example output, I suspect that there is a detail missing that is causing this, but I can't seem to track it down? Whilst the code compiles, I'm unable to use the properties without manually adding in the parameters, which defeats the purpose somewhat. Any idea what is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment #3 on [this DevCity article](http://www.devcity.net/Articles/71/codedom_1.aspx) suggests it shouldn't matter, but I do know that [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) does behave as you're expecting, although it *may* have it's own implementation for code generation...